# Why was the Phantom Zone "gateway" so close to Earth that the hydrogen bomb shattered it?

Tags: dc, superman

This is about the 1980 movie *Superman II* with Reeve and Hackman.

The only information I noticed in the film itself was this line from Superman's mother:

> The one danger we have considered is that the Phantom Zone might - we cannot predict - just might be cracked by a nuclear explosion in space. I cannot say I am glad you asked me that -

This almost makes it sound like a nuke *anywhere* in space would shatter the Phantom Zone, but if that was the case it ought to only take one supernova or warring space-capable civilization anywhere in the universe to shatter it, in which case it wouldn't have lasted very long.

So what's special about the part of outer space around Earth that makes the Phantom Zone gateway nukeable from there? Did the gateway follow Superman's <s>christmas ornament</s> spaceship all the way from Krypton to Earth or something?

Comment: Surely it's depicted just as a coincidence? The revolving mirror thing happened to be floating past the earth just as Superman threw the bomb from the Eiffel Tower.

Comment: The [script](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/movies/superman_II_shoot.txt) is just baffling. It talks about traveling to other galaxies; "*WIDE SHOT -- Superman, with the speed of light zooms through the Universe, past the
Moon with the Earth growing smaller in the distance. Faster and faster he goes until he bursts through into another galaxy.*"

Comment: Seems like this should have a tag specific to the movie Superman II, but I don't see one to add.

Comment: I don't recall the details of how Zod and his gang end up on Earth. Did a nuke in space break the glass rectangle thing? Next to Earth? That *does* seem a bit coincidental.

Answer (score 1):

In this movie the Phantom Zone is a prison that travels through space and you could argue that the Zone was caught in Krypton's explosion and followed a similar path as Kal El's ship.

Furthermore, later in the movie, Superman grabs the nuke in Paris and disposes of it by throwing it in deep space where it just happens to explode near the wayward Phantom Zone. Yes, it's a plot contrivance but all of fiction is a contrivance.

And it's not a nuke anywhere in space; it's just that the Zone is strong, but not strong enough to survive a big enough explosion.

Answer (score 1):

It's not explained how, or indeed why, the Phantom Zone was *so close to Earth* in either the film or its official novelisation. That being said, if we look at the earlier (1976) script treatment, it's explained that **the Phantom Zone is intended to remain in orbit around Krypton.**

> **JOR-EL**: (a trifle uneasily) *No one, not even the scientists or Krypton, can predict  all eventualities throughout all eternity. The
> one danger  we have considered is that the Phantom Zone might, just
> might -- we cannot know -- be cracked by a major nuclear  explosion in
> space.*
>
> EXTREMELY TIGHT CLOSEUP LEX LUTHOR -- He sits bolt upright, his eyes
> shining.
>
> **JOR-EL**: *But our computers show this possibility as .000000002  in one million. Earthlings cannot travel this far in space,  nor would
> they ever have reason to cause such an explosion. So I think we can
> consider the Phantom Zone secure.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Superman II - '76 Treatment](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/movies/supermanii_scriptment_2_76.txt)</sup></sub>

It follows that the Phantom Zone was likely pushed out of orbit by the explosion of Krypton, and then followed the same trajectory as Kal-El's pod toward Earth. This is also the standard explanation given as to why so much Kryptonite has landed on Earth.

Answer (score 0):

Well, perhaps when the rocket ship was sent from Krypton if you remember in the new version with the added scenes the ship passed by them in space so maybe, it was caught in the rockets trajectory, even though it left them behind because it was much faster letting them drift the same way the ship was going, and eventually getting to our galaxy? Maybe?

Comment: Probably not.  Getting caught in somethings wake or slipstream is something that happens in an atmosphere or in the presence of matter. The object barreling through pushes air/water out of the way, leaving a bit of a vacuum behind them, and the remaining matter in the area rushes in to fill that void, and that's what pulls someone along, or helps them to move with less resistance.In space the propulsion from the ship would actually push other objects in the opposite direction.